# Exception & Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I have code written on .net core 2.0. I need to throw an exception. That is, there is a line in the code line

```
throw new Exception();
```

When I run the code on the Windows an exception is thrown. But when I try to run it on the Ubuntu the application just ends. As an IDE I use a Rider.
Am I doing something wrong? How to generate an exception on the Ubuntu?

Comment: which ide on windows?

Comment: and what kind of app? console? how exactly do you get indication that the exception is thrown on Windows?

Comment: how you habdle it? and ..are you using .net core or mono on Linux?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and I'm sorry! The Rider does not show the window with the exception, but if I make the exception handling I'm calling code, then everything works!   Console application, .net core 2.0